# What is wrong with my .ctags file?

Tags: php, ctags

I am a ctags newbie, coding in PHP. I have found this ctags file online:

```
-R
--exclude=.svn
--tag-relative=yes
--PHP-kinds=+cfpd
--regex-PHP=/abstract\s+class\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/
--regex-PHP=/interface\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/
--regex-PHP=/(public\s+|static\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)\$([^     =]+)/\2/p/
--regex-PHP=/const\s+([^    =]+)/\1/d/
--regex-PHP=/final\s+(public\s+|static\s+|abstract\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)function\s+\&?\s*([^ (]+)/\2/f/
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
$ ctags
ctags: Warning: Unsupported parameter 'p' for --PHP-kinds option
```

From experimentation I see that the `p` needs to be defined, and in fact it is defined on the seventh line of the file. So why is the error being thrown?

**EDIT:**
The ctags file came [from here](https://github.com/lucasoman/Conf/blob/master/.ctags), which was linked from [this terrific article](http://lucasoman.blogspot.com/2010/09/vim-php-taglist-and-ctags.html).

Here is the output of my configuration:

```
$ ctags --version
ctags: Warning: Unsupported parameter 'p' for --PHP-kinds option
Exuberant Ctags 5.6, Copyright (C) 1996-2004 Darren Hiebert
Compiled: Jan  6 2007, 02:10:54
Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
$ cat ~/.ctags
-R
--exclude=.svn
--tag-relative=yes
--regex-PHP=/abstract\s+class\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/
--regex-PHP=/interface\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/
--regex-PHP=/(public\s+|static\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)\$([^ \t=]+)/\2/p/
--regex-PHP=/const\s+([^ \t=]+)/\1/d/
--regex-PHP=/final\s+(public\s+|static\s+|abstract\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)function\s+\&?\s*([^ (]+)/\2/f/
--PHP-kinds=+cpdf
$ ctags
ctags: Warning: Unsupported parameter 'p' for --PHP-kinds option
$
```

Comment: Please link the source where you have found that file.

Comment: What characters are in the character class: `[^     =]` on that line? If one is a tab, try replacing it with `\t`.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question with the file source.

Comment: @sarnold. Thanks. I have replaced the literal tab in the `p` line and the `d` line with `\t` but it had no effect. I am still getting the same error (and no error for `d`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'p' kind is not defined for PHP by default.

```
--regex-PHP=/(public\s+|static\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)\$([^     =]+)/\2/p/
```

is defining a 'p' kind for PHP in your case.  If you move

```
--PHP-kinds=+cfpd
```

after this, it will not give you an error.

**Note:** Here is my version info for ctags:

```
$ ctags --version 
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Apr 19 2012, 11:31:19
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

Comment: Incidentally, that gets rid of the warning and does give you p entries in your tags file.  The next step would be arguing what a p entry is and if you really want one.  =D

Comment: Thank you. Moving the `--PHP-kinds` line either directly after the `p` line, or even to the end of the file, does not resolve the issue for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: hmm.. it solved the issue for me and Lucas Oman.  What version of ctags are you using, and can you post your .ctags file?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with the configuration information.

Comment: @dotancohen That's a fairly old version of ctags.  I'd suggest updating to 5.8.  I added my version information to my answer.